# Oracle Apex Dynamic action not working for form items

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a form with items P1_APP and P1_USER.

P.S. P1_USER is select list.
Display John
Return 1
Display Andy
Return 2

I need to disable when user selects John.

When P1_USER = 'John', P1_APP should get disabled which is a multi select list.

I created dynamic action on P1_APP, True Action= Disable,Affected element P1_APP

```
Client condition : Item =Value 
Item= P1_USER
Value= John
```

However this is not working.

I have used similar logic to disable interactive grid items and was able to do so. Why is this not working for form?

EDIT: In Value now i am putting 1 which is return value for John.
However when i select John. It disables P1_App upon clicking. But remains disabled even when i choose Andy.

Comment: Works well for me; just tested it.

Comment: Also just tested it, works fine.  You aren't confusing 'John' the display value with whatever the returned value is are you?  The DA works off the returned value.

Comment: My bad, i did not mention. Yes its a select list. John would return 1 and Andy would return 2. Now it did disable when i selected John and put 1 . But When i change to Andy, it is still disabled. I want this disabled only for John

Comment: Edited post with details, now issue is fires only once and remains so until page is loaded.

Comment: Should i make another post for clarity?

Comment: No need, you can just update this one.  Now it sounds like you are missing the FALSE action for the DA, to enable when != John?

Comment: You mean add a false action to this existing da? But there isn't option to add a condition. Should i create new da with false action?

Comment: not a condition - a "false" action. You create the DA with a true action of "Disable". You also need the opposite: a false action of "Enable".

Comment: I tried that too, its not working. i.e. after changing selection it remains disabled

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Please provide more information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me using the following configuration.

1. Create form and report on EMP - everyone has access to that sample data, it is a good idea to post questions based on that.
2. In the form P3_DEPTNO is a select list with source

```
SELECT d.dname, d.deptno FROM dept d
```

3. Add a page item to my form P3_APP. This is a select list with "Allow multi selection" enabled. Select list has 2 static values.
4. Create a dynamic action on change of P3_DEPTNO.
   Client side condition: Item = Value
   Item: P3_DEPTNO
   Value: 30 (note that this is the return value for SALES, not display value)
5. add true action of "Disable", affected item P3_APP
6. Click true action and select "Create Opposite Action". Save.

When I run this it work. Selecting SALES in the select list disables the item P3_APP and selecting something else enables it.